# What does the ViewGroup argument represent in 'onCreateViewHolder'

Tags: android

I am following a newbie tutorial in Android and currently RecyclerView has been introduced.

```
    public NumberViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
      Context context = parent.getContext();
      int layoutIdForListItem = R.layout.number_list_item;
      LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
      View view = inflater.inflate(layoutIdForListItem,parent,false);
      NumberViewHolder holder = new NumberViewHolder(view);
      return holder;
    }
```

What does the `parent` variable represent in my application? Does it represent the layout that all these views should be added to? If that's true then how come I don't need to explicitly call `addView` on it?

Comment: Basically, it's just the `RecyclerView`. It's passed into that method primarily so you can give it to the `LayoutInflater` so it can apply the appropriate `LayoutParams` to the inflated `View`.

Comment: @MikeM. Why does my view need the RecyclerView layout params?

Comment: If your `View` doesn't have `LayoutParams` set during inflation, then all of the `layout_*` attributes you have in the XML are lost, and it gets stuck with the defaults. For example, this is really noticeable in a vertical `RecyclerView`, when the `layout_width` is lost, and the `View`s all wrap their widths, so they don't cover the full width of the `RecyclerView`.

Comment: @MikeM. On a slight tangent. Does the inflater convert xml into a ViewGroup? I have googled this for a while and it's never a firm answer

Comment: Basically, yeah. It just reads through the layout, creates an instance of each `View` and its `LayoutParams`, and adds it to its parent, if necessary. It doesn't have to be a `ViewGroup`, though. You could have a layout that's just a single `View`; e.g., a `TextView` for a `ListView` row. You could do the same thing in your code, but it's arguably easier to let `LayoutInflater` do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#onCreateViewHolder(android.view.ViewGroup, int)

> parent: The ViewGroup into which the new View will be added after it is bound
>   to an adapter position.

So, it will basically just be the RecyclerView view where inflation can happen with appropriate layout paramters.

Comment: Okay, I guess this is worth another question? Why do I need the RecyclerView layout parametres? (and on another note) The documentation keeps mentioning a hierarchy? 'Inflate a new view hierarchy from the specified xml resource.' Is that just saying it is creating a ViewGroup with all my views inside it?

Answer (score 1):

It represents the ViewGroup into which the new View will be added after it is bound to an adapter position. That means the parent of the view to be added.